# .config issues in app.js of ionic project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get my ionic app.js running with my new factory and am having problems locate an error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and think its a simple mistake. I create a plunker so its easier to look at. If you can help me it would mean a lot. Here is a plunker. Thank you

```
ionic.bundle.js:13438 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `ng-app="starter"` to `body` tag.

Eg.

```
<body ng-app="starter">
```

Comment: any other ideas? The issue started when I tried to add my factory into this file. If i revert it back to the original without the factory it works but i need the factory

Comment: I cant figure it out! Ive been banging my head against the wall. Its definitely the script code http://plnkr.co/edit/aXTUutcsRECPVv2wJQ8J?p=preview